# Softwares needed for developing Iphone

Tags: iphone

I am planning to do a application in iphone.
Could you please tell me what software/s will I need?

Comment: a google search for 'iPhone development' would have found you the right answer.

Comment: bing "iphone sdk" would have found you the right answer

Comment: You need a Mac running Mac OS X, first. You can buy that from Apple.

Answer (score 3):

You will need iPhone SDK.
http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
But you will mostly have to pay for it , it is a professional program !

This complete developer toolset for creating Mac, iPhone, and iPad apps includes the Xcode IDE, performance analysis tools, iOS Simulator, and the latest Mac OS X and iOS SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an iPhone game I would recommend cocos2d game engine, you will also need XCode as your IDE and Mac OS.